# Java getElementById() or Alternative

Tags: java, xhtml, getelementbyid

So, I have an XHTML document report skeleton that I want to populate by getting Elements of a certain IDs and setting their contents.

I tried getElementById(), and had null returned (because, as I found out, id is not implicitly "id" and needs to be declared in a schema).

```
panel.setDocument(Main.class.getResource("/halreportview/DefaultSiteDetails.html").toString());
panel = populateDefaultReport(panel);

Element header1 = panel.getDocument().getElementById("header1");
header1.setTextContent("<span class=\"b\">Instruction Type:</span> Example<br/><span class=\"b\">Allocated To:</span> "+employee.toString()+"<br/><span class=\"b\">Scheduled Date:</span> "+dateFormat.format(scheduledDate));
```

So, I tried some work-arounds because I don't want to have to validate my XHTML documents. I tried adding a quick DTD to the top of the file in question like so;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ATTLIST bar id ID #IMPLIED>]>
```

But getElementById() still returned null. So tried using `xml:id` instead of id in the XHTML document in the hopes it was supported, but again no luck. So instead I tried to use getElementsByTagName() and loop through the results checking ids. This worked, and found the correct element (as confirmed by output printing "Found it"), but when I try to call setTextContent on this element I am still getting a NullPointException. Code below;

```
    Element header1;
    NodeList sections = panel.getDocument().getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (int i = 0; i < sections.getLength(); ++i) {
         if (((Element)sections.item(i)).getAttribute("id").equals("header1")) {
            System.out.println("Found it");
            header1 = (Element) sections.item(i);
            header1.setTextContent("<span class=\"b\">Instruction Type:</span> Example<br/><span class=\"b\">Allocated To:</span> "+employee.toString()+"<br/><span class=\"b\">Scheduled Date:</span> "+dateFormat.format(scheduledDate));
        }
    }
```

I'm loosing my mind on this one. I must be suffering from some kind of fundamental misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work. Any ideas?

Edit; Excerpt from my XHTML file below with CSS removed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Details</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p></p>
        <img src="#" alt="Logo" height="81" width="69"/>
        <p id="header1"><span class="b">Instruction Type:</span> Example<br/><span class="b">Allocated To:</span> Example<br/><span class="b">Scheduled Date:</span> Example</p> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should mention that what you're trying to achieve first?

Comment: @Makky I want to get an element with a certain id, and then set it's contents. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create an html from java bean or something ?

Comment: I am creating an XHTML, to be viewed in Flying Saucer, who's elements will have content specified by Entity objects. I am in the process of trimming my HTML file to the bare minimum to understand the problem. Will post it up shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why its not working , but I have put together example for you and it works !

Note : My example is using following libraries

1. Apache Commons IO ([Link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/))
2. Jsoup HTML Parser ([Jsoup link)](http://jsoup.org/)
3. Apache Commons Lang ([Link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/))

My input xhtml file ,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Site Details</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p></p>
        <img src="#" alt="Logo" height="81" width="69" />
        <p id="header1">
            <span class="b">Instruction Type:</span> Example<br />
            <span class="b">Allocated To:</span> Example<br />
            <span class="b">Scheduled Date:</span> Example
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The java code that work ! [All comments, read ]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //loading file from project
        //When it is exported as JAR the files inside jar are not files but they are stream
        InputStream stream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.xhtml");

        //convert stream to file
        File xhtmlfile = File.createTempFile("xhtmlFile", ".tmp");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(xhtmlfile);
        IOUtils.copy(stream, fileOutputStream);
        xhtmlfile.deleteOnExit();

        //get html string from file
        String htmlString = FileUtils.readFileToString(xhtmlfile);

        //parse using jsoup
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

        //get all elements
        Elements allElements = doc.getAllElements();


        for (Element el : allElements) {
            //if element id is header 1
            if (el.id().equals("header1")) {

                //dummy emp name
                String employeeName = "dummyEmployee";
                //update text
                el.text("<span class=\"b\">Instruction Type:</span> Example<br/><span class=\"b\">Allocated To:</span> "
                        + employeeName.toString() + "<br/><span class=\"b\">Scheduled Date:</span> " + new Date());
                //dont loop further
                break;
            }
        }

        //now get html from the updated document
        String html = doc.html();

        //we need to unscape html 
        String escapeHtml4 = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(html);

        //print html 
        System.out.println(escapeHtml4);

    }

}
```

**output **

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Site Details</title> 
  <style type="text/css">
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="header"> 
   <p></p> 
   <img src="#" alt="Logo" height="81" width="69" /> 
   <p id="header1"><span class="b">Instruction Type:</span> Example<br/><span class="b">Allocated To:</span> dummyEmployee<br/><span class="b">Scheduled Date:</span> Sat Nov 02 07:37:12 GMT 2013</p> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer. I've accepted it, but I actually used Java standard XML DOM parser, which has done the trick.